# UI isn't at correct position

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, google-vr

I have a issue about UI, when i build and run on my android device, game looks like we can see in the following screenshot. Middle line and gear button are not at correct position.

[image: android]

There is no problem in Unity Editor.

[image]

What could it be problem?

Comment: What is your device?

Comment: It looks like [this issue](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/315) on their github

Comment: Samsung S4 android 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It is not incorrect. Google is changing the position of the buttons. The horizontal line will be like it is in your screenshot. The Unity Editor has not been updated yet. Source: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/351

Comment: Yeah, probably right. If there is a calculating issue, gear would be at bottom of the screen which is an unseenable position. But in my opinion google should change it. This line doesn't seem right. Anyways, thanks for replying!

Comment: @BurakAlpYaşar you can suggest that (on github, not here) if you wish ;)